# customizable aspects in spring

Tags: java, spring, customization, spring-aop

I’d like to apply a customizable aspect on two different services (spring bean). My problem is how/where to set/define the pointcut expression. One normally defines the pointcut expression on a ‘dummy method’ or directly on the advice method. However that means the pointcut is static (not customizable).
I’d like to define the pointcut at the bean creation level to be able to create the same kind of advice for different targets. Ideally I’d like to do something like this:

```java
@Aspect
public class ServiceAspect {
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceAspect.class);

   private final String discriminator;

   // no advice defined here!!!
   public ServiceAspect(String discriminator) { this.discriminator = discriminator; }

   public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
      LOG.info(discriminator + " called");
      return jp.proceed();
   }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ServiceConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public MyService service1() { return new MyServiceImpl(); }

   @Bean
   @Around("bean(service1)") // define the advice when bean is created
   @ConditionalOnProperty("aspect1Enbaled")
   public ServiceAspect aspect() {
      return new ServiceAspect("Aspect-1");
   }

   @Bean
   public YourService service2() { return new YourServiceImpl(); }

   @Bean
   @Around("bean(service2)") // define a different advice when bean is created
   @ConditionalOnProperty("aspect2Enbaled")
   public ServiceAspect aspect() {
      return new ServiceAspect("Aspect-2");
   }
}
```

Notice that the @Around annotation is on the definition of the bean. I can thus reuse the aspect for different target. Using the @ConditionalOnProperty, this would enable me to turn on/off individual aspect base on a property.
Can anyone help me with this? I suspect I’ll need to create some kind of factory but can’t seem to see how I can REPLACE an already defined bean (the service bean) with a proxy!

Comment: The concept of AOP is to model a cross-cutting concern separately from the core code. By pulling the pointcut definitions into your applicatiion configuration, you are violating this principle, Apart from that, it is technically not possible to define `@Around` just anywhere outside an aspect. Furthemore, you are trying to define two aspect instances of `ServiceAspect`. What if both conditions are true? This is all very contrived. And BTW, the pointcuts are just as static because they are residing as annotations inside compiled code. Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I do partially agree with you in that AOP is, at its core, a cross-cutting concept. Yet we are able with AspectJ to target a specific method of a specific interface/class/instance if needed which is the exact opposite. Don't you agree?
What I'm trying to implement is in fact a file-caching aspect to my services. Yet constraint dictate that each service should have a dedicated cache in a given directory (hence customizable).
I could create a given class for each cached-service but that is counter-productive if I have 100 services: so is it possible to dynamically bind a pointcut to an aspect?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There are several approaches to achieve what you want. Some are specific to Spring AOP (Spring's built-in, proxy-based "AOP lite" approach), others would only work if you activate the well-documented full AspectJ support for Spring via LTW (load-time weaving). Yet another approach would work via annotation processing, also with AspectJ, during compile time, dynamically creating one aspect per class or cache. Is AspectJ an option for you or does it have to be Spring AOP with dynamic proxies? My answer depends on yours.

Comment: I'm already using AspectJ in my project so it is definitely an option but somehow I get the feeling the Spring proxy-based "AOP lite" approach is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, for the rest of the week I will be pretty busy. Maybe I can follow up on this during the weekend.

Comment: I just remembered this again, sorry for the long absence. I have another question before we proceed: How do you intend to determine which bean should be cached? And what does the cache instance and/or cache directory in the file system depend upon? Is it one cache per bean class? One per bean instance? Something completely different? I would like to narrow down the options a bit because when thinking about how I would do this I noticed that my decision would depend on the answer to those questions as a minimum plus maybe other factors.